# Sublime text 3 run a python script and stay in interactive mode after (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, sublimetext3

I have a custom build system which executes a python script and shows the output in the terminal. I would like to stay in the interactive mode afterwards (be able to access variables). How would I change the JSON code below?

```
{
    "cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"python3 -u $file;read line\"'"],
    "shell": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the python interactive mode option `-i` to the command : `"gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"python3 -i -u $file;read line\"'"`